# Computing the Limit of Multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do we compute the limit of following function?

$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{sin(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

If someone can give me some hint then that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

setting $t=x^2+y^2+z^2$ we get
$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$